# Why log4j won't create file?

Tags: java, logging

i am trying to create a .log file for my app.
logs are going out to the console, but not on file.
Here is my .properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/user/Downloads/demo/src/main/resourceslogigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This is the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this is the injection in the @RestController class:

```
//SFL4J


    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(message, User.class);
            logger.info("New message read successfully!");
```

Comment: if you are using slf4j for logging then you have to add an alsf4j log4j binding as long as the log messages are logged with log4j ...

Comment: That version of log4j is very old. Consider upgrading.